# nginx + uwsgi + virtual environment. What goes inside?

Tags: python, nginx, flask, virtualenv, uwsgi

Seems like a simple question but I cannot find it addressed anywhere. Every tutorial I look at does things slightly differently, and I'm pretty sure I've seen it done both ways.

In my development environment, python, flask, and all other dependencies of my application go inside the Virtual Environment.

When configuring a production environment, do Nginx and uWSGI go inside the virtual environment?

Thanks!

Comment: I simply started to confuse myself because I've seen uWSGI installed outside and inside the VE, so I wanted to be thorough with this question. So I guess there's half my answer. nginx doesn't go inside the VE. Thanks.

Comment: I normally don't see any reason to use virtualenv on a prod server. It only adds a lot of complexity. The only reason would be if you want to host a lot (to much) different projects with separate dependencies on that server.

Comment: That is a good point, RickyA. This server will only be serving a single application so the added complexity of a VE is not necessary. That being said, I'd hate for this question to be pointless... so do you know if uwsgi should go inside our outside a VE?

Comment: then dont use virtualenv, and save a lot of headache.

Comment: If you plan/foresee the use of multiple versions of uwsgi (very,very unlikely) put it in venv. Otherwise put it in global.

Comment: just keep your prod servers simple. If you plan to do multiple deployment it is better to use something like docker for each separate project/microservice.

Comment: Thanks for all the help, Ricky. You made this make way more sense. Will you submit an answer so I can accept it (and you get credit)?

Comment: We specify virtual env in uwsgi config not uwsgi in virtual env.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, Nginx never goes in Virtualenv. It is a os service and has nothing to do with python. It only serves webrequests and knows how to pass them to a upstream service (like uwsgi).

Second; don't put things in virtualenv that don't need seperate versions. Uwsgi is quite stable now, so you will almost never need separate versions; so don't put it in venv.

Third; when you plan for production deployment, keep things as simple as possible. Any added complexity will only make the chance of failure higher. So do not put venv on your prod servers until your absolutely need it. And even then you are probably putting to much stuff on that server. Keep your servers single minded. I find it easier to use multiple machines (especially with cloud services like AWS) that each have one purpose than to cram everything on one big machine (where one screwball process can eat all the mem for everybody else)

Forth; When you do need more python projects/services it is better to separate them with things like docker, since then they are better maintainable and better isolated from the rest.

Comment: If you want to use new python features, the system-wide uwsgi could very well not support that python version, so you need to use a newer one then. Also, setting up the project by installing the dependencies from a lock file that was created by poetry or pipenv makes your deployment more similar to your development or test environment,it helps with reproducibly; putting the exact versions of the python dependencies on the server for this project. Separating python projects with their library versions in virtualenvs is also a good separation if nothing else changes much between projects.